# How to move a certain pattern of subfolders to another folder, keeping the structure using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a set of folders like:

```
/path/to/group1/folder/number123
/path/to/group1/folder/number456
/path/to/group2/folder/number123
/path/to/group2/folder/number456
/path/to/group3/folder/number123
/path/to/group3/folder/number456
```

And I want to move folders that match `/path/to/group*/folder/number123` 
to the base folder `/path/toOther/` so that after the move it looks like:

```
/path/to/group1/folder/number456
/path/to/group2/folder/number456
/path/to/group3/folder/number456  

/path/toOther/group1/folder/number123
/path/toOther/group2/folder/number123
/path/toOther/group3/folder/number123
```

Is there a way to do this with a move command and wild cards, or will it require more than a 1-liner?

Comment: The `cp` command only takes a single destination directory. So you need  a loop to iterate through the destination directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind writing a few lines:

```
cd /path/to
for f in group*/folder/number123
do
    d="/path/toOther/${f%/*}"
    mkdir -p "$d"
    mv "$f" "$d/."
done
```

Of course you can combine the script into one line. (Or the `bash` will do this when you recall it with the <kbd>Up</kbd> key.)